# Handling large gaps for time series forecasting (TFT model)

Tags: time-series, data-cleaning, forecasting, data-preprocessing

I have an hourly time series data which contains both short and large missing gaps. For small gaps I could use linear interpolation technique to fill the missing points but I would like to learn what are the best practices to fill the large gaps? My goal is to prepare data to train a TFT (Temporal Fusion Transformer) model and as far as I know I cannot simply remove the gaps because the data would not be continuous anymore and that causes issues. I'd appreciate any suggestions, Thank you!

Comment: The most rigorous option is probably to take the last contiguous piece of your time series, predict from that, and ignore the previous piece entirely. A less rigorous option which uses more of your data could be to use TFT or ARIMA to fill in the gap between the two time series. I worry that linear interpolation over large gaps would decrease seasonal coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

For filling in missing values in Time series data, there could be multiple methods.

1. Feed Forward: Simply carry forward the last available values. F(t+1) = F(t), if F(t+1) is missing.
2. Backword Fill: Simply impute the next available values. F(t) = F(t+1), if F(t) is missing.
3. Seasonal Fill: Simply impute the next, or last seasonal available values, and also may take the average. F(t) = F(t+m), if F(t) is missing, m is the seasonal period.
4. Simple Polynomial Interpolation: Simply interpolate the imputed values by using polynomial functions.
5. State Space Models (Bayesian Forecasting): Use posterior distribution to impute missing values.
6. Model-based Inference: FB Prophet is a good time series forecasting method. One can use these methods to predict the values of missing data and then impute them instead of missing values. Also, tree-based ensemble methods, Transformer models (TFT), and RNN are good. However, there must be some caution (critically analysing the pros and cons of the chosen method) when applying these models.